# Packaging .net MVC application as exe or msi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, wix, publish

We have a .net MVC application where it involves deployments every week. We need to package the application and give it to the clients every week for them to install as an .exe or .msi

The package will involve DB changes also and site in IIS is already set.
The exe/msi just has to replace the old files(bin and views) and do the DB changes(run scripts). I don't want client to see either our code or DB script while installing.

So how can I achieve this as a single package?

Comment: Do you use Entity framework code first? Is webdeployment ok for you?

Comment: No we are not using entity framework.I have not tried webdeployment. Does it comply with my requirement?

Comment: With entity framework code first, you can enable migration. That means that entity will automatically add the steps to update the database based on your model. Then, you create a webdeploy zip file that contains the source and the migration data. When you deploy the file, the database will be updated.